# How to optimize Arch linux boot time?

Tags: boot, arch-linux

I've had Arch Linux installed on my system for a while now, but the problem is that it takes way too much time to boot. And so, I'm trying to optimize the boot process. A Google search led me to [`quick-init`](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=25563) but the its' AUR page says its out-of-date. So, I just want to make sure if I should use this? Or are there any other ways?

Comment: Would be extra nice if you included a link, so that I don't have to do the search myself.

Comment: You might also provide some information as to exactly where the boot process is slow... That would help with suggestions and recommendations.

Comment: @Tshepang- added the link

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend the e4rat package. A detailed how-to is on [sourceforge](http://e4rat.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) as well as in [this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5790311/e4rat-cuts-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-a-few-simple-commands).

Comment: You would be better off providing a link to the official Arch information on the Wiki: it is tailored for Arch and won't go out of date like the Lifehacker article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/E4rat

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses the `ureadahead` package.  It might take some work to get it going on Arch, but should be possible. See the [Ureadahead](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ureadahead) page on the Arch wiki.

Answer (score 1):

In your `/etc/rc.conf` there should be a "DAEMONS" line (see [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rc.conf#Daemons)). This is a list of all of the daemons that will start on system boot. You can specify that a daemon should be started in the background, i.e. don't wait on it to finish starting before continuing, by prefixing a "@" to the daemon name. For example, on my XBMC box I have the following:

```
DAEMONS=(syslog-ng network !netfs crond @acpid @sshd @httpd @samba @alsa @openntpd !dbus @avahi-daemon @mtd @lircd @autofs)
```

This box boots very quickly.